# How to get the original sentence from a text file by knowing an offset of a word in python?

Tags: python, nltk, text-files, offset

I am new to python and I wonder if there is an efficient way to find the original sentence from a text file by knowing an offset of a word. Suppose that I have a test.txt file like this:

test.txt

```
Ceci est une wheat phrase corn.
Ceci est une deuxième phrase barley.
This is the third wheat word.
```

Suppose that I know the offset of the word "wheat" which is [13,18].

My codes look like this:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

with open("test.txt") as f:
    list_phrase = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    contents = f.read()
    for index, phrase in enumerate(list_phrase):
        j = word_tokenize(phrase)
        if contents[13:18] in j:
            print(list_phrase[index])
```

The output of my codes will print both sentences i.e ( "Ceci est une wheat phrase corn." and "This is the third wheat word." )

How to detect exactly the real phrase of a word by knowing its offset?

Note that the offset that I considered continues between many sentences (2 sentences in this case). For example, the offset of the word **"barley"** should be [61,67].

The desire output of the print above should be:

```
Ceci est une wheat phrase corn.
```

As we know that its offset is [13,18].

Any help for this would be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code looks about right.  If 'wheat' is contains in more than one phrase, what do you want to happen?  Do you want all the matches printed, or just the first?

Comment: how did you get the offsets? can you just collect the lines at the same time?

Comment: @ti7-- I got it from another codes. Suppose here I know the offset of word and want to find its original sentence from a text(compose of many phrases)

Comment: @TimRoberts-- If wheat contains in many phrases. I want to print only a phrase that matched with its offset in the whole text.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for raw speed then the standard library is probably the best approach to take.

```
# Generate a large text file with 10,000,001 lines.
with open('very-big.txt', 'w') as file:
    for _ in range(10000000):
        file.write("All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.\n")
    file.write("Finally we get to the line containing the word 'wheat'.\n")
```

Given the `search_word` and its `offset` in the line we're looking for we can calculate the `limit` for the string comparison.

```
search_word = 'wheat'
offset = 48
limit = offset + len(search_word)
```

The simplest approach is to iterate over the enumerated lines of text and perform a string comparison on each line.

```
with open('very-big.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line, text in enumerate(file, start=1):
        if (text[offset:limit] == search_word):
            print(f'Line {line}: "{text.strip()}"')
```

The runtime for this solution is `155 ms` on a 2012 Mac mini (2.3GHz i7 CPU). That seems pretty fast for processing 10,000,001 lines but it can be improved upon by checking the length of the text before attempting the string comparison.

```
with open('very-big.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line, text in enumerate(file, start=1):
        if (len(text) >= limit) and (text[offset:limit] == search_word):
            print(f'Line {line}: "{text.strip()}"')
```

The runtime for the improved solution is `71 ms` on the same computer. It's a significant improvement but of course mileage will vary depending on the text file.

Generated output:

```
Line 10000001: "Finally we get to the line containing the word 'wheat'."
```

**EDIT:** Including file offset information

```
with open('very-big.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_offset = 0
    for line, text in enumerate(file, start=1):
        line_length = len(text)
        if line_length >= limit and (text[offset:limit] == search_word):
            print(f'[{file_offset + offset}, {file_offset + limit}] Line {line}: "{text.strip()}"')
        file_offset += line_length
```

Sample output:

```
[430000048, 430000053] Line 10000001: "Finally we get to the line containing the word 'wheat'."
```

**Encore une fois**

This code checks if the known offset of the text is between the values of the offset of the start of the current line and the end of the line. The text found at the offset is also verified.

```
long_string = """Ceci est une wheat phrase corn.
Ceci est une deuxième phrase barley.
This is the third wheat word.
"""

import io

search_word = 'barley'
known_offset = 61
limit = known_offset + len(search_word)

# Use the multi-line string defined above as file input
with io.StringIO(long_string) as file:
    file_offset = 0
    for line, text in enumerate(file, start=1):
        line_length = len(text)
        if file_offset < known_offset < (file_offset + line_length) \
        and (text[(known_offset-file_offset):(limit-file_offset)] == search_word):
            print(f'[{known_offset},{limit}]\nLine: {line}\n{text}')
        file_offset += line_length
```

Output:

```
[61,67]
Line: 2
Ceci est une deuxième phrase barley.
```

Comment: I think here, your answer is that you consider each offset for the individual sentence. Like I mentioned before, the offset I want to find is the offset count continuously from the beginning of the sentence to the word that we want to find.

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you know the offset of the word and you want to get the sentence that matches this criteria. You are providing the offset from the start of the line and the word. If you don't know the offset to the word and are instead looking for a list of lines in a text file where the word appears including the offset from the start of each line I wouldn't implement the solution in Python. Instead I'd use a tool like `awk` because it will scale much better.

Comment: Nagel-- Can you propose a solution when the offset continuously count from the start? Like the word **barley** I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You want to find the locations of the word `barley` in your text file?

Comment: Nagel-- I want to find the original sentence of each word by knowing its offset. Note that the offset I mention here it must be count continuously in the text file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_Note that the offset I mention here it must be count continuously in the text file._" Can you give an example that I can follow to try to understand?

Comment: The example of word **"barley"** as I mentioned in my question is [61,67]. the offsets of 61 and 67 is the position if you count from the start of the text file not counting from its own phrase i.e. (Ceci est une deuxième phrase barley.)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the code for counting the offset from the beginning of the text file. You can amend the output to suit your needs. Please accept the answer if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Nagel-- My question is that suppose I know the offset [430000048, 430000053] not the offset  48 and I want to find the original sentence.

Comment: @Ben10 : Edited the answer to provide your expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the position of the word, tokenizing is not what you want to do. By tokenizing, you change the sequence (for which you know the position) to a list of words, where you don't know which element is your word.

Therefore, you should leave it at the phrase and just compare the part of the phrase with your word:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    list_phrase = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    contents = f.read()
    for index, phrase in enumerate(list_phrase):
        if phrase[13:18].lower() == "wheat": ## .lower() is only necessary if the word might be in upper case.
            print(list_phrase[index])
```

This would only return the sentences where `wheat` is at the position `[13:18]`. All other occurrences of wheat would not be recognized.

Comment: I tested it. it prints 3 sentences which are wrong. it supposes to print only one sentence.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I confused two variables. It should have been: `phrase[13:18]`, not `contents[13:18]`. I changed it in the code above.